# How to simulate analog VU meter

Tags: analog, simulation

I've designed circuit to drive an analog VU meter for my project, but I would like to test it in circuit simulation program before I build it.
Unfortunately, there is no such thing as 'VU meter' in the circuit simulation program that I'm using, so I have to use other components to make something that behaves as close as possible to real VU meter(I guess it's called equivalent circuit).
I'm not sure how to do that.
My first idea was that impedance of VU meter is inductive, so I can approximate VU meter using an inductor.

> The reading of the volume indicator shall be 0 VU when it is connected to an AC voltage equal to 1.228 Volts RMS across a 600 ohm resistance (equal to +4 [dBu]) at 1000 cycles per second.
>   The VU meter and its attenuator should present a 7,500-ohm impedance to the circuit it is applied to, measured with a sinusoid signal that sets the indicator to 0

Inductor that has 7.5k impedance at 1kHz has inductance of approximately 1.19H.
However when I use just 1.19H inductor in place where VU meter would be in my circuit I get rather weird results.

I heard that some meters have integrated rectrifiers, and some doesn't. 
My circuit is designed for one without integrated rectrifier.
So what is the correct way to approximate VU meter?

Comment: It must have rectification to get quasi-peak but  some rise and fall times desired are your choice

Comment: Would https://www.circuitlib.com/index.php/schematics/product/43-needle-vu-meter/category_pathway-28 be of any use?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 It has external rectification, I mentioned in my question that my circuit is designed for non-rectifier VU meter type(yes, I know that such meters can't really be called VU meters, but they are just as good for my needs, and significantly cheaper)

Comment: Yeah, I guess rise and fall times are my choice, but I asked how to model VU meter using only basic components that are available in my software.

Comment: @Transistor Well, this article tells me that VU meters are 'based on passive microampere-meters (150μΑ-DC) fed from full-wave diode-rectifiers', which I already know, and show me how to design driver circuit, which I already have. What I don't know is what exactly does 'based' mean, and how to implenent such microampere-meter in simulation software(one again, I'm not interested in actual readings, I just want to be sure that my circuit is working properly and won't add distortion to my audio signal) Thank you for the comment

Comment: The term "based" means that the circuit is designed around that particular moving coil meter (rather than design the electronics and try to find a meter to suit). You should get resistance and inductance values from a suitable moving-coil meter datasheet.

Comment: What do you want to simulate?  Rotary positive of a coil needle with momentum or R/L = Tau electrical time constant  or simple quasi-peak and decay slow or what? Your question is too vague.  You are asking for specs on something defined poorly.  It is basically a peak responding rotary motor with open circuit spring return and not a galvometer low impedance drive.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm sorry if question is too vague. I have a circuit that incorporates VU meter into my project, but I want to simulate it before I build it. The problem is that on my drawing of the circuit I can just draw a rectangle with two wires and label it 'VU meter', but there's no such component in software I'm using. I meant to ask what should I put into my circuit in simulation software in place where rectangle labeled 'VU meter' used to be. Perhaps I should rewrite my question?

Comment: I was expecting to get something like this in answer, but for VU meter instead of vacuum tube http://www.vias.org/albert_ecomm/aec08_electronic_apps_communication_021.html

Comment: @JK You'll need to carefully read the [Wikipedia page on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VU_meter), as you are, and then refer to the documents mentioned there. Most especially, I noticed that they used two copper-oxide rectifiers placed across a normal d'arsonval meter movement and that there are some precision specifications in terms of settling time and other details (behavior at different frequencies, for example.) You'll need to develop your own equivalent, if this is only about "software" simulation. It's just math. Work it out from the specs.

Comment: You have a reasonable understanding of how a simple VU is made but not how to define software specs for it.  A good VU meter serves 2 functions a) average listening volume and peak power relative to any full scale undistorted output. regardless of impedance or voltage.  The 0dB references often indicates 3dB red margin to high distortion and/or clipping.  Explained here https://bluebuzzmusic.com/best-free-vu-meter-plugin-vst/   There are many free simple VU meter programs for Windows as well and many no so simple you can examine specs by interface at all OSI levels from visual to bit stream.

Comment: Although audio interfaces tend to follow standard levels for various interfaces, such as ~1Vrms for "Line levels"  Start from your UX or user experience interface, range, response, resolution, function, average (period) peak (hold time) https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03iCCpvHGCRDh4S4jjv7Y8QOe_cow:1591804779761&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=vu+meter+download&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz4cvzzvfpAhWgZzABHZkwBtIQsAR6BAgLEAE&biw=1043&bih=751   For more specs https://sound-au.com/project55.htm